# I need an English expression ( preferably slang ) to express my willingness and commitment to do something

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests, phrase-requests, expression-choice, idiom-meaning

I need an English expression ( preferably slang ) to express my willingness and commitment to do something ( e.g I will put my heart and soul into it )

Comment: The question (and subsequent answers) are related, but they address a depth of commitment rather than one's willingness to be deeply committed.

Comment: What's the context? Enthusiastically picking up a "one-night stand" in a bar? Being ready and willing to get involved in a fist-fight? Convincing the interviewer that you *really* want the job?

Comment: "On board" is one possibility.

Comment: You are "up for it"

Answer (score 2):

There's a phrase which comes from poker, when one places all of his chips in, in demonstration that he is totally committed to this hand.

## I'm all in

> be all in: 1. To be fully committed to a task or endeavor; to give or be prepared to give all of one's energy or resources toward something.

([The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I%27m+all+in))